# How to continue looping through GLfloat Points

Tags: c, opengl, glut, nurbs

I am having trouble making a simple drawing.

I'm not sure what the issues is here but I have a set of points:

```
GLfloat ctrlpoints[13][3] = {
        {0.1, 0.1, 0.0},
        {0.7, 0.1, 0.0},
        {0.9, 0.1, 0.0},
        {0.9, 0.3, 0.0},
        {0.7, 0.3, 0.0},
        {0.6, 0.3, 0.0},
        {0.55, 0.25, 0.0},
        {0.5, 0.2, 0.0},
        {0.2, 0.2, 0.0},
        {0.12, 0.2, 0.0},
        {0.1, 0.3, 0.0},
        {0.07, 0.2, 0.0},
        {0.1, 0.1, 0.0} };
```

And I want all the points in the code to connect but instead it stops after the 6th set of points.

Rest of my code:

```
void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glMap1f(GL_MAP1_VERTEX_3, 0.0, 1.0, 3, 5, &ctrlpoints[0][0]);
    glEnable(GL_MAP1_VERTEX_3);
}

void display(void)
{
    int i;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
        glEvalCoord1f((GLfloat)i / 30.0);
    glEnd();
    glPointSize(0.5);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        glVertex3fv(&ctrlpoints[i][0]);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off [the documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMap1.xml), the 5th argument to `glMap1f` is the number of the points. You set it to `5`, so that's the number of control points that are used for evaluation. You should replace it with 13, or use `sizeof` to compute that number automatically:

```
int npoints = sizeof(ctrlpoints)/sizeof(ctrlpoints[0]);
glMap1f(GL_MAP1_VERTEX_3, 0.0, 1.0, 3, npoints, &ctrlpoints[0][0]);
```

---

This is not what you were asking, but in this loop you also render less points (twelve) than you declare (thirteen):

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
```

You should similarly use `npoints` to get the right number. Magic constants like these are bad exactly because they cause mistakes of this sort.